# Finding the MAP for a function whose conditioning depends on an exponential integral

Tags: probability, distributions, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution, map-estimation

Let $X$ be such that $X  \sim exp( \lambda = 1)$ and let $Y$ be such that $Y \sim U[0,x]$, where $x$ is the  realization of $X$.

Given that information I know that:

$f_{X}(x) = e^{-x}$ for $x \geq 0$

$f_{Y|X}(y|x) = 1/x$ for $x \geq 0$

Now, supposing $y = 2$ and knowing that, mathematically, the MAP is:

$\hat{x}_{MAP} = arg. max f_{X|Y}(x|y)$.

I knew that to calculate the MAP, I'd need to derive $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ in relation to $x$ and set it equal to zero so I could solve for $x$. But the equation is:

$f_{X|Y}(x|y) = \dfrac{f_{X}(x) . f_{Y|X}(y|x)}{f_{Y}(y)}$

With the information I am given, I can affirm that $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{X}(x) . f_{Y|X}(y|x) = \dfrac{e^{-x}}{x}$ for $x \geq 0$.

Then I tried to calculate the PDF for the variable $Y$ since the PDF of $Y$ is in the denominator. The range of $Y$ is $[0,x]$ so I assumed that the realized value of $X$ is the constant $a$. This way the limits of my integration won't be confused with the variable of integration itself. Then

$f_{Y}(y) = \int_{0}^{a} \dfrac{e^{-x}}{x} dx$.

With the help of an online calculator, I got that

$f_{Y}(y) = \text{Ei}\left(-a\right)-\text{Ei}\left(0\right)$, where $\text{Ei}$ is the [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral). This is definitely not what I was expecting and I feel like I might be overcomplicating things.

Is this the best way to keep up with the calculation or (a) did I miss something or (b) made some wrong assumption?